# Angular Ionic - Why doesn't click method work?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Angular 2 &
Ionic 3

**Project Structure (code below image)**

[image: directory structure]

I defined a custom click method in the home.ts file that is supposed to be triggered by a button in the home.html file.

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic 2 Basics
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="onGoToUsrs">Users</button>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UsersPage } from '../users/users';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  onGoToUsrs() {
    this.navCtrl.push(UsersPage);
  }

}
```

The home page appears in the browser as expected, button included. The button is clickable, but triggers nothing when clicked. There are no errors in the console. I tried to run a console.log() in the click method but it did not run, hopefully that detail helps.

I've tried restarting the server after making changes.

Why doesn't the button trigger the custom click method?

Comment: I think you click: `(click)="onGoToUsrs"` should be this: `(click)="onGoToUsrs()"`, unless that is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onGoToUsrs needs () to call the function

```
<button ion-button (click)="onGoToUsrs()">Users</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on your code in template file.

```
    <button ion-button (click)="onGoToUsrs">Users</button>
```

It Should be -

```
    <button ion-button (click)="onGoToUsrs()">Users</button>
```